# Por que `position: sticky;` de um elemento para de funcionar ao chegar a `margin-bottom` do próximo elemento?

Tags: html, css3, posicionamento, margin

Estou fazendo um exercício de `CSS` e tenho um `header` estilizado com `position: sticky`. Esse estilo funciona corretamente até o momento em que o scroll da página encontra a `margin-bottom` do próximo elemento (`div`), quando o `header` deixa de ser "sticky". Porém, com `margin-top` no `div`, o código funciona normalmente. O imprevisto é apenas com `margin-bottom`. 
Dei uma pesquisada, mas não consegui encontrar uma explicação para esse comportamento, nem como o evitar. Ficarei grato se alguém puder elucidar esse assunto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Desafio Menu</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #333 ;
        }

        .cabecalho {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .logo img {
            float: left;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .logo {
            width: fit-content;
            height: fit-content;
        }

        ul {
            background-color: #000;
            white-space: nowrap;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .menu li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .menu a {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            background-color: #999;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 25px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .menu a:hover {
            background-color: yellow;
            color: black;
        }

        .menu a:active {
            background-color: brown;
        }

        .menu a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: inherit;
        }

        .menu-toggle {
            display: none;
            float: right;
        }

        .autenticacao {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            height: 70px;
            right: 2.5%;
        }

        .autenticacao a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: white;
            position: relative;
            top: 25px;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px white ;
            background-color: tomato;
        }

        .autenticacao a:active {
            color: #fff;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        .logo a {
            font-size: 0px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 816px) {
            .cabecalho ul {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="cabecalho">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#inicio">
                <img src="http://site/curso-web/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <button class="menu-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#inicio">Início</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#cursos">Cursos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#sobre">Sobre</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contato">Contato</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <aside class="autenticacao">
            <a href="#login">Login</a>
            <a href="#registar" class="botao destaque">Registrar</a>
        </aside>
    </header>
    <div style="height: 2000px; margin-bottom: 1000px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use um padding bottom no container que vc quer espaçar, deve resolver o problema

Answer (score -1):

Consegui entender o comportamento.
Um elemento posicionado como `sticky` permanece assim até chegar ao fim do conteúdo da box do elemento pai. No caso, o elemento pai de `header` é `body`. Sendo assim, `header` só permanece "sticky" enquanto o browser estiver mostrando o conteúdo de `body`.
Percebi, então, que o `margin-bottom` do `div` que inseri após `header`não pertencia ao conteúdo de `body`. Por isso, `header` não permanecia mais no topo da janela após alcançar o `margin-bottom` do `div`. Do mesmo modo, se for adicionado algum elemento antes de `header`, e ele possuir um `margin-top`, `header` só será "sticky" abaixo da altura que `margin-top` ocupar.
Conclui, então, que estilizar o cabeçalho com `position: fixed;` atenderia melhor às minhas necessidades.